# Reading data from mscomm in ABAP

Tags: abap

I'm trying to [read data sent from serial port](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/07/10/read-comm-port-using-abap-wo-third-party-software/) via [MSCOMM32](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/139526/how-to-send-to-the-serial-port-by-using-mscomm32-ocx) object.

What I got was `##`.

First I convert hex into string and send to COMM port:

```
DATA : xSTX TYPE xstring VALUE '02'.
DATA : sSTX TYPE string.

CALL FUNCTION 'HR_KR_XSTRING_TO_STRING'
EXPORTING
 in_xstring = xSTX
 IMPORTING
 out_string = sSTX. "this value is now # but still understood by the device

SET PROPERTY OF O_OBJ 'Output' =  sSTX .
```

And then the machine attached to serial port will give a response. I read the data using this code below:

```
  Data strmsg Type string.
  DO 10 TIMES.
    GET PROPERTY OF o_obj 'InBufferCount' = wa_buffer.
    If wa_buffer > 0.
        GET PROPERTY OF o_obj 'Input' =  strmsg.
    Endif.
  ENDDO.
```

I can see the response using monitoring device but the input that I get was only `##`, when I convert this `##` into hex then I would get `0202`.

I already did all the settings correctly because I'm able to send the data and activate the machine, but I'm still not able to translate the response.

I have a legacy software using .NET and it can read the data perfectly, using the same response data.

Another strange thing was the value of `sSTX` is `#` but I don't bother it too much because it's understood by the device.

The expected output is (taken from monitor)

```
<ACK><STX><STX><NUL><SOH>01000000000000000000000000                       P3                                                                                                                                                    <ETX>
```

But all I get was 060202 which is

```
<ACK><STX><STX>
```

somehow the text body is not in the same space.

I know the answer is there but I just can't figure it out for weeks. very weird.

Comment: Sorry but this is a question no one could understand. Please provide some more details.

Comment: Does [this](https://answers.sap.com/questions/303977/serial-comm-port-input-value-contains-questions-ma.html) fix it for you?

Comment: It is also discussed a little in the [topic referenced in the post](https://answers.sap.com/questions/7339938/read-comm-port-using-abap-wo-third-party-software.html) I linked before, you should read it all and check if you did everything and if there is any port settings that you might have to adjust.

Comment: Legxis, no if I used that code the result is just 0000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @Jagger Basically they have connected something to the computer using the COMM port and want to read something from it into SAP.

Comment: We are produce [hardware device](https://www.isisdanismanlik.com/en/urun/iot-applications-22) for getting data to SAP from serial/parallel equipment. It is not stable getting data with COM/ActiveX object.

Comment: If it's not too long, can you post the different parts of the legacy .NET code, and the corresponding ABAP code for each part?

Comment: you should add sample of input, then your current output and expected output

Comment: SerialPort spL = (SerialPort)sender; indata = indata + spL.ReadExisting();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

set the inputlen property to 4.
solve the problem.