# How To Use Serial Port Monitor

Tags: abap

Hi I created a program let's say using ABAP and I want to monitor the data sent to my serial port (COM port)

Now there are a lot of software out there that can help me monitor this transaction.

But the problem is that the software only built to monitor data send from outside the computer.

For example some device sending data through com port to your pc.

BUT when you send the data from your PC to serial port it will raise an error on PORT is already open.

The way the port monitor software works is first opening the port and the read the data send to the serial port.

The problem happens when my own custom program try to send data to serial port, where I also need to open the port first.

So in order for my program to work then I have to shutdown the serial monitor software (this way I cannot use the monitor program).
But If I turn on the monitor software, then it will open a port that will make my program to become error and cannot open a port (I cannot send any data to serial port).

If I send data using my program without opening a port then it will send nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading data from mscomm in ABAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727401/reading-data-from-mscomm-in-abap)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use com port emulator software. Generally these programs create virtual comport for listening. You application must connect to this virtual port.

Some of these emulator programs can connect virtual port to the real port. So you can get inbound and outbound data.